# Writing duplicate data when using Log4j in Jboss webservice

Tags: java, web-services, logging, jboss, ejb

I am using Log4j with Jboss EJB webservice.  I am logging the application flow in the File.

This is the code I am using for logging

```
 FileAppender fileappender;

    File file = new File("jws_" + getCurrentDate("dd_MMM_yyyy") + ".log");

            Logger log = null;
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() );
    try
    {
        log = Logger.getLogger(ConnMan.class);
        fileappender = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(),"f2cjws_" + getCurrentDate("dd_MMM_yyyy") + ".log");
        log.addAppender(fileappender);


                    if (!theLogLevel.equalsIgnoreCase("error"))
                    {
                        if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(getProperties().getProperty("log")))
                        {
                            log.debug(getCurrentDate("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 1")+" "+theError);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.debug(getCurrentDate("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 1")+" "+theError);
                    }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Logger failed due to "+e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Logger failed due to "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

When I run the application, I am getting duplicate data in my file, i.e.., same data is written twice or thrice.  The above code worked fine in webapplication deployed in tomcat.

So I feel I am missing something in related to JBoss.

This webservice now currently uses the log4j properties built in with the server.  Can I know how to make it to use application's own properties file?

Please help me,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Am I the only one that sees the completely random indenting? I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you.  Can you be more specific?  Thanks

Comment: .. I think you are quite going on wrong way .....

Comment: @water Yeah I feel the same.  Can you please correct me or offer any other solution?

Comment: Why don't you use default appenders?

Comment: I had  the same issue. Instead of writing my own LogWriter as suggested in the accepted answer, all I had to do was to make Logger a static class level variable instead of a local (method scope) variable.With this change it ceased creating duplicate log entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your own log writer,

```
public final class LogWriter
{

    private static Logger appLogger = null;

    private static String className = LogWriter.class.getName() + ".";

    static
    {
        try
        {
            appLogger = Logger.getLogger("Demologer");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void logDebug(String message)
    {
        appLogger.log(className, Level.DEBUG, LogWriter.getMessage(message), null);
    }


    public static void logInfo(String message)
    {
        appLogger.log(className, Level.INFO, LogWriter.getMessage(message), null);
    }

    public static void logError(String message)
    {
        appLogger.log(className, Level.ERROR, LogWriter.getMessage(message), null);
    }

    private static String getMessage(String message)
    {
        String retValue;

        Calendar cale = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = cale.getTime();

        //retValue=now.getDate()+"/"+(now.getMonth()+1)+"/"+(now.getYear()+1900)+"  "+now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes()+":"+now.getSeconds();
        retValue = now + "\n";

        now = null;
        cale = null;

        return retValue + message;
    }
}
```

---

You can use this one as you need.

Comment: oh, you can edit the first one to update your answer.  Thanks for the update

Comment: your solution works.  Only one doubt.  This is a heavy traffic webservice.  Is creating static methods cause any problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you have some thing like following in your log4j.properties you will see duplications in output:

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, myappender
log4j.logger.com.sample=warn, myappender 
log4j.logger.com.sample.deeper.package=all, myappender
```

correct it to:

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, myappender
log4j.logger.com.sample=warn 
log4j.logger.com.sample.deeper.package=all
```

Edit:

Following will write fatal and error level logs from every classes, fatal, error and warning level logs from com.sample.* classes and every logs from com.sample.deeper.package.* classes to /var/log/myappender/myappender.log file.

Save as log4j.properties in you root package:

```
# This appender is not used in this example.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c - %m%n

# But this one is used.
log4j.appender.myappender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.myappender.File=/var/log/myappender/myappender.log
log4j.appender.myappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.myappender.Encoding=UTF-8

log4j.rootLogger=error, myappender
log4j.logger.com.sample=warn 
log4j.logger.com.sample.deeper.package=all
```

In your every classes you need a logger:

```
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ThisClassName.class);
```

And you don't need the snippet code you have in you question any more.

Comment: Actually my webservice takes the default log4j properties file available in Jboss.  Can you tell me how to make it to look the properties of mine?

Comment: As far as I remember loading properties files obey loading other type of resource in Java classpath, so a properties file in your classpath will override all other properties files in same package in your jars. I will added a sample in my response, wait a min!

Comment: Updated!! (+More chars to feed StackOverflow!!)